# If $f$ is holomorphic, then there is a holomorphic function $h$ such that $e^{h(z)}=f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, exponentiation

Let $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ denote a holomorphic function over a star-shaped domain $G$ and $f\ne 0$ on $G$. I want to show that it holds

1. $\frac{f'}{f}$ is holomorphic
2. There is a holomorphic function $h:G\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $e^{h(z)}=f(z)$ for all $z\in G$

(1): Since $f$ is holomorphic, $f'$ is holomorphic too. Moreover $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ is also holomorphic on $f(G)$. So the composition $\frac{f'}{f}$ should be holomorphic as well - no other arguments needed, right?

(2): A hint asks to determine all [entire functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function) $f,g$ with $$f^2+g^2=1$$ and to show $f+ig=e^{ih}$ with an entire function $h$. I think the first equation has something in common with $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$, but I can't put the pieces together and find the relation to the actual question.

**EDIT**: According to *Daniel Fischer's* comment: Since $f$ is a holomorphic function on a star-shaped domain $G$ $$F:G\to\mathbb{C}\;,\;\;\;\int_{[z_0,z]}f(\zeta)d\zeta$$ (where $z_0$ is the center of $G$) is a holomorphic function with $F'\equiv f$ on $G$. So, I think we should have $$e^{h}=f\Leftrightarrow\int e^{h(z)}dz=F(z)$$

Comment: Ad (1), $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ need not be holomorphic on $G$ (we could have $0\in G$), but that isn't what you use anyway. $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, so $z \mapsto \frac{1}{f(z)}$ is holomorphic on $g$. Ad (2), I think the better hint is that on a star-shaped (more generally, simply connected) domain, every holomorphic function has a primitive.

Comment: I think (2) is not a hint, but instead an application of the result.

Comment: @Daniel (1) Sorry, what I meant was $f(G))$ (2) Could you be more precise? What is a primitive of a (holomorphic) function and why does it exist?

Comment: I thought it was just a glitch in the write-up. A primitive is what you may know under the neologism of "antiderivative" (gah, I hate that unword).

Comment: For (2) notice that $f^2 + g^2 = (f+ig)(f-ig) = 1$ which means $f(z)+ig(z)$ is nonvanishing for all of $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Now apply the exponential result.

Comment: @DanielFischer Now I know what you mean. I've updated my question accordingly. How do I proceed?

Comment: You don't need a primitive of $f$ here, but a primitive of a different holomorphic function on $G$. One that was also mentioned.

Comment: @DanielFischer Now I know what you mean. I've updated my question accordingly. How do I proceed?

Comment: If $f = e^h$, what is the derivative of $h$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Since $$f'=h'e^h$$ it should be $$h'=\frac{f'}{e^h}$$

Comment: So far so good. What was $e^h$?

Comment: $e^h$ was $f$, so $$h'=\frac{f'}{f}$$ which is a holomorphic function (as said by (1)). But we already know that $f$ has a holomorphic primitive (in your words ;). That was far too easy. Thanks